# Prevent overlapping scrolling

Tags: css, scroll, css-position

I have a design issue in my app, the body text is scrolling through my nav- and command line and i don't know how to fix it. I'm not looking for a z-index fix where the body text flows underneath, i want to restrict the lorem ipsum filler text upper scrolling to just below the command bar. The body text is huge, and scrolling is necessary. Currently it looks like this:

[image]
Navbar CSS:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
```

Command Line:

```
margin-bottom: 60px;
```

Body Text:

```
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
```

I'm using Microsofts ui-fabric grid system, and can post more code if necessary. But i was hoping there would be an easy "set vertical scrolling breakpoint for this div at x pixels from top" - or something like that. But i can't seem to find anything.

I guess i don't understand this well enough, so if someone can explain the big picture of how to resolve this scrolling issue, that would be helpful.

Comment: Does the navbar need to be always visible? Or do you want it to move to the top (and out of screen) with the text?

Comment: Yes, i would like the navbar and command line to be visible at all times (and they are with my current setup)

Comment: So your issue is the navbar is sitting over the body text and you'd like the body text to start from below the navbar but then be able to scroll behind it?

Comment: If i understand you correct, yes. I want the body text to treat the lower part of the command line area as top of the page, so that the body text stops scrolling at just that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the height of the container in which the text is to a specific height and then set the overflow on the y axis to scroll, this will result in the behavior you want because the scroll is limited to the container div, thus the text won't scroll through the navbar.

Remember to adjust the margin from the top accordingly so it starts under your nav and command bar.

Example (assuming your navbar is 10vh):

```
#text-container {
  height: 90vh;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If your navbar is for example 100px you could do:

```
height: calc(100vh-100px);
margin-top: 100px;
```

This would correct the height so it will always fill your whole screen.

If a horizontal scrollbar appears you can hide this with `overflow-x: visible;` or `overflow-x: hidden;`depending on the behavior you want

Comment: Correct answer I guess, can I just ask why you use view height instead of px or vw?

Comment: Of course, personally i prefer the view height so the div would fill the whole screen on every device (in the height), vw is of course for the width and with px the scrollable area could be really big or really small depending on the resolution. Therefore I use vh (here assuming your navbar is approximately 10vh) @Wimanicesir

Comment: Looks like it might work, but is there any way to "invert" the height? Currently 90vh makes the lower part of the screen empty, i need it to start from top instead.

Comment: @melbil, you can use the part i just added (using `calc()`) in order to adjust the height from the full height with the height of your nav and commandbar, then it should fill the whole screen

Comment: I'm trying that, but it still calculates from bottom-up (10% of the lower part of the screen is invisible - i need 10% of the upper part of the screen to be invisible). Also, i get an unnecessary horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Did you specify margin-top on the text-container to the height of your navbar and command bar? The horizontal scrollbar can be hidden with `overflow-x: visible` or `overflow-x: hidden` @melbil

Answer (score 0):

To start with an offset on the body text just give it a margin-top which is the same height as you nav bar, i.e.

```
margin-top: 50px;
```

This will give your body an initial spacing before it starts, after the user starts scrolling it'll

Answer (score 0):

```css
.full_width {
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

Comment: try to elaborate more detail on your answer as for learning